# How do I retrieve all columns for all matching rows with Perl's Net::Cassandra::Easy?

Tags: perl, nosql, cassandra, thrift

When using Perl's `Net::Cassandra::Easy` the following code will retrieve columns `col[1-3]` from rows `row[1-3]`:

```
$result = $cassandra->get(['row1', 'row2', 'row3'], family => 'Standard1', byname => ['col1', 'col2', 'col3');
```

The corresponding SQL would be:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM rows WHERE id IN ('row1', 'row2', 'row3');
```

Suppose instead that I want to retrieve all columns. In SQL terms that would be:

```
SELECT * FROM rows WHERE id IN ('row1', 'row2', 'row3');
```

To get all columns I am currently using:

```
$result = $cassandra->get(['row1', 'row2', 'row3'], family => 'Standard1', byoffset => { "count" => 1_000_000 });
```

This works as long as the number of columns does not exceed one million. While this works I'd assume that there is a cleaner way to do it. Is there any cleaner way to specify to Cassandra that I want to retrieve all columns for the matching rows?

Comment: Not familiar with Cassandra, but couldn't you run a query earlier to get the table structure, so you'd know how many columns are available?

Comment: Wonder if the developer who made this had an ex named Cassandra that he didn't like too much...

Comment: zigdon: Nope :-)  The "table structure" in Cassandra is dynamic in the sense that one row can have say five columns whereas the next row has say forty columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
$result = $cassandra->get(['row1', 'row2', 'row3'], family => 'Standard1', standard => 1);
```

`standard => 1` will force Net::Cassandra::Easy to use a slice predicate that matches all columns in the family.